# Moving voronoi texture

Tags: texturing

everyone!
I use Voronoi texture as windows on distant buildings.
It looks OK at a single render picture. But in a full scene with a moving camera texture moves too. It looks like a timelapse with blinking windows. Cool, but i don't need it.
I have to stop it somehow. )

Please, give a hint. Or may be you know a better way for distant buildings?

[image]

Comment: can you share your file with that building and camera + render settings? It shouldn't blink at all, I just tried to replicate it (just in case) and it works as intended... The problem is not in your material but in something else

Comment: Have you tried this rendered? This problem appears precisely in the camera view or render.

Comment: yes I rendered it in both eevee and cycles, nothing, there is no reason that this would blink, that's why I am asking you for more details or your file

Comment: Yes, looks like the problem is somewhere else... 
I tried it in a new project. It works good.
May be it's because of snow animation... may be not. 
Snow emitter is far away from buildings? close to cam.

Answer (score 1):

You can bake the voronoi texture into a fixed image. Select the object and unwrap it (smart UV or lightmap pack can get the job done). Then in the shader window create an image texture node, set its resolution, press new to create a new image and leave the node selected and unconnected.

Switch to cycles, go to bake tab, select emission and click bake.
Save your newly create image and use it in the node tree of the image.

[image]